# Try to use the codeigniter's file upload library as a general function from Helpers

Tags: codeigniter

Can anybody help as I am trying to use the codeigniter's upload library from the helpers folder but I keep getting the same error that I am not selecting an image to upload?  Has any body tried this before?

```
class FileUpload extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'file_uploading'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation', 'upload');
    }

    public function index() {
        $data = array('title' => 'File Upload');
        $this->load->view('fileupload', $data);
    }

    public function doUpload() {
        $submit = $this->input->post('submit');
        if ( ! isset($submit)) {
            echo "Form not submitted correctly";
        } else { //            Call the helper
            if (isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
                $result = doUpload($_FILES['image']);
                if ($result) {
                    var_dump($result);
                } else {
                    var_dump($result);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Helper Function

```
<?php
function doUpload($param) {
    $CI = &get_instance();
    $CI->load->library('upload');
    $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|png|jpg|jpeg|png';
    $config['file_name'] = date('YmdHms' . '_' . rand(1, 999999));
    $CI->upload->initialize($config);
    if ($CI->upload->do_upload($param['name'])) {
        $uploaded = $CI->upload->data();

        return $uploaded;
    } else {
        $uploaded = array('error' => $CI->upload->display_errors());

        return $uploaded;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you have it working before you tried implementing it this way?

Comment: No always the same error

Answer (score 0):

There are some minor mistakes in your code, please fix it as below,

```
$result = doUpload($_FILES['image']);
```

here you should pass the form field name, as per your code `image` is the name of file input.

so your code should be like

```
$result = doUpload('image');
```

then, inside the function `doUpload` you should update the code 
from

```
$CI->upload->do_upload($param['name'])
```

to

```
$CI->upload->do_upload($param)
```

because Name of the form field should be pass to the `do_upload` function to make successful file upload.

> **NOTE**
>
> Make sure you added the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form
>   element

Comment: @StephenZammit if the code works, mark the answer as accepted, click on the checkmark beside the answer